# Find an example of a random vector $X$ with its sub-gaussian norm much larger than any of its coordinates'.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, normed-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Can any one give me an example of random vector $X = (X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ such that $$||X||_{\psi_2} \gg \max_i||X_i||_{\psi_2}.$$
Here $||X||_{\psi_2} = \sup_{x\in S^{n-1}}||\langle X,x\rangle||_{\psi_2}$ and $||X_i||_{\psi_2} = \inf\left\{t>0:E\left(\exp\left(X_i^2/t^2\right)\leq2\right)\right\}$.
This is a question from high-dimensional probability and what I know is that if the coordinates of $X$ are independent then $||X||_{\psi_2} \leq C \max_i||X_i||_{\psi_2}$ for some constant $C$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Let $X_i:=Y$ for all $i\in\left\{1,\dots,n\right\}$. Then 
\begin{align}
\left\lVert X\right\rVert_\psi&=\sup_{x\in S^{n-1}}
\left\lVert \left\langle x,X\right\rangle\right\rVert_\psi\\
&=\sup_{x\in S^{n-1}}
\left\lVert \sum_{i=1}^n x_iY \right\rVert_\psi\\
&= \sup_{x\in S^{n-1}}\left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right\rvert 
\left\lVert Y \right\rVert_\psi
\end{align}
and since $\sup_{x\in S^{n-1}}\left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right\rvert $ is achieved for $x_i=1/\sqrt n$, we get
$$
\left\lVert X\right\rVert_\psi\geqslant \sqrt n\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}\left\lVert X_i \right\rVert_\psi.
$$